# A property over positive numbers shouldn't shrink to negative numbers

Tags: scala, scalacheck

In ScalaCheck, I have a property test that uses a generator of positive integers that when it fails ScalaCheck will shrink to a non-positive value.

Shrinking is supposed to help find the minimal failing case.  Shrinking to values outside of the desired range is confusing and unhelpful.  This is a known bug, see [ScalaCheck issue #129 Gen.suchThat not respected by shrinking](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/129)

Is it possible to define my own shrinking instance in scope so that it will only shrink to positive integers?

### Example

Here's a minimal property test:

```
class ShrinkProp extends Properties("Shrink") {
  property("posNum[Int]") = {
    Prop.forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { _: Int =>
      Prop.falsified
    }
  }
}
```

This will typically cause ScalaCheck to shrink the argument to zero:

```
[info] Done compiling.
[info] ! Shrink.posNum[Int]: Falsified after 0 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: 0
[info] > ARG_0_ORIGINAL: 1
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

Or worse, it could on occasion shrink to a negative value:

```
[info] ! Shrink.posNum[Int]: Falsified after 5 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: -1
[info] > ARG_0_ORIGINAL: 3
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

### Disable shrinking

One solution is shutting off shrinking with `forAllNoShrink`:

```
class ShrinkProp extends Properties("Shrink") {
  property("posNum[Int]") = {
    Prop.forAllNoShrink(Gen.posNum[Int]) { _: Int =>
      Prop.falsified
    }
  }
}
```

The result is no shrinking:

```
[info] ! Shrink.posNum[Int]: Falsified after 0 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: 1
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

### Adding guards

Another alternative is adding a guard to the test, so that he shrunk values or just skipped:

```
import Prop.BooleanOperators

class ShrinkProp extends Properties("Shrink") {
  property("posNum[Int]") = {
    Prop.forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { x: Int =>
      (x >=  1) ==> Prop.falsified
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an alternative to disabling shrinking and adding guards?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a shrinker in ScalaCheck for positive integers.  You have to write your own.

### Overview

A `Shrink` needs to be defined as an `implicit` in scope of your property test.  Then `Prop.forAll` will find the right `Shrink` class if it is in scope and has the appropriate type signature for the value that failed a test.

Fundamentally, a `Shrink` instance is a function that converts the failing value, `x`, to a stream of "shrunken" values.  It's type signature is roughly:

```
trait Shrink[T] {
  def shrink(x: T): Stream[T]
}
```

You can define a `Shrink` with the companion object's `apply` method, which is roughly this:

```
object Shrink {
  def apply[T](s: T => Stream[T]): Shrink[T] = {
    new Shrink[T] {
      def shrink(x: T): Stream[T] = s(x)
    }
  }
}
```

### Answer: Shrinking positive integers

A shrinker for positive integers is a `Stream` that shrinks by halving the value to find the smallest failing case through binary search, but stops before reaching zero:

```
class ShrinkProp extends Properties("Shrink") {

  implicit val posIntShrinker: Shrink[Int] = Shrink { x: Int =>
    Stream.iterate(x / 2) { x: Int =>
      x / 2
    }.takeWhile { x: Int =>
      x > 0 // Avoid zero.
    }
  }

  property("posNum[Int]") = {
    Prop.forAll(Gen.posNum[Int]) { _: Int =>
      Prop.falsified
    }
  }
}
```

Proof that failure is working:

```
[info] ! Shrink.posNum[Int]: Falsified after 6 passed tests.
[info] > ARG_0: 2
[info] > ARG_0_ORIGINAL: 4
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

Even better, you could write a property to verify your shrinker behaves as it should:

```
property("posIntShrinker") = {
  Prop.forAll { x: Int =>
    val shrunk = Shrink.shrink(x)
    Prop.atLeastOne(
      (x >= 2) ==> shrunk.size > 0,
      (x <= 1) ==> shrunk.isEmpty
    )
  }
}
```

```
[info] + Shrink.posIntShrinker: OK, passed 100 tests.
[info] Failed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
```

It would be nice to write a generic positive numbers `Shrink` that would be able to shrink other types of numbers, like `Long`, the floating point types and `BigDecimal`.